# How to get src attribute from <image/> with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping data from one site, and I need to find one img.
I get it but the output is not what I need.

I have tried looking online for solutions, changing code but nothing worked.

```
r = requests.get(baseurl)
content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

images = soup.findAll('img')[1]
print(images)
```

Output I get:

```
<img src="https://cdn.rubyrealms.com/images/WKpivrdGBJJ9p6etIY2aJpixikFj4vnpmpPR9pXjK4Y8K.png" style="border-radius: 5px"/>
```

Output I need:

```
cdn.rubyrealms.com/images/WKpivrdGBJJ9p6etIY2aJpixikFj4vnpmpPR9pXjK4Y8K.png
```

(I tried print(images.text))

Comment: Parse the `src` attribute from your `<img>` element

Comment: Try `images.get('src')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get the `img` tag's `src` content using ;

```
images = soup.findAll('img')[1]
print(images.get("src"))
```

**or**

```
images = soup.findAll('img')[1]
print(images['src'])
```

**Output**

```
https://cdn.rubyrealms.com/images/WKpivrdGBJJ9p6etIY2aJpixikFj4vnpmpPR9pXjK4Y8K.png
```

The problem with `print(images.text)` is that it is used to extract the text in between two tags and you want to extract the text which is inside the tag itself.

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample you can adapt:

```
parser.feed('<img src="python-logo.png" alt="The Python logo">')
Start tag: img
attr: ('src', 'python-logo.png')
```

REFERENCE: https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html